# Case Statement isn't joining the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's my query

```
SELECT migrationref,
       dbo.Firstnamecheck(firstname, contacttype)         AS FirstNameCheck,
       dbo.Lastnamecheck(lastname, contacttype)           AS LastNameCheck,
       dbo.Corporatenamecheck(corporatename, contacttype) AS CorporateNameCheck,
       dbo.Advisercheck(adviser, advisermigrationref)     AS AdviserCheck
INTO   ##clientvalidcheck
FROM   clientimports

DELETE FROM ##clientvalidcheck
WHERE  ( firstnamecheck IS NULL
         AND lastnamecheck IS NULL
         AND corporatenamecheck IS NULL
         AND advisercheck IS NULL );

SELECT *
FROM   ##clientvalidcheck

SELECT CASE firstnamecheck
         WHEN 'ERROR' THEN 'FirstName caused an Error.'
       END "FNValidationError"
FROM   ##clientvalidcheck;
```

To my understanding when you use a case statment it adds a column to the end of your table to show the results from the statement however for me it's producing a new column that is not part of the table. Is there anyway to join the two?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Please don't tag products not involved.

Comment: You need to include the `case` inside your select * if that's what you want, not as a separate statement.

Comment: @jarlh Sorry I am only using MS SQL Server

Comment: you seem to be saying that you are expecting a new column, but that in fact you are getting a new column that you didn't expect?

Answer (score 1):

modify like it

```
Select t1.*, CASE t1.FirstNameCheck WHEN 'ERROR' THEN 'FirstName caused an Error.' END "FNValidationError"
FROM ##ClientValidCheck  t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Select A1.*, CASE A1.FirstNameCheck WHEN 'ERROR' THEN 'FirstName caused an Error.' END "FNValidationError"
FROM ##ClientValidCheck  A1;
```

Comment: attention to "," before case   ;)